# Manage browser history manually for one part of my Turbolinks-enabled Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, html5-history

I am using Turbolinks but I would like to take over history management for one piece of my application's flow. Specifically:

1. User loads product page
2. User clicks on product and product modal appears (without reloading the page)
3. Upon loading the product model the URL updates to the loaded product's URL
4. User clicks "back"
5. The model disappears and the user returns to the product page *but the product page doesn't reload*

If I manually `history.pushState(null, null, PRODUCT_URL)` after the user clicks in step (2) then everything works except step (5) during which Turbolinks reloads the entire product page.

Ideally I could hook into the `window`'s `popstate` event and cancel Turbolink's ajax request, but per Turbolinks docs "Restoration visits cannot be canceled and do not fire `turbolinks:before-visit`"

Comment: were you able to find a working solution to this problem with turbolinks and dialogs? I'm having the exact same issue (dialogs and turbolinks back button re-rendering entire page).

Comment: @DanL you're not going to like this answer, but no I never found a working solution and in fact I've since removed Turbolinks from the app entirely and rely exclusively on the native `history` API. In addition to this functionality gap Turbolinks just created too many small issues to be worth the hassle. Which is very sad because I love it in theory!

Answer (score 3):

When pushing to the history, Turbolinks adds its own data to the `state` (i.e. the first argument to `history.pushState`. It then uses this data on the `popstate` event, to restore the page.

To manually push to the history in the format the Turbolinks understands, rather than calling `history.pushState` directly, you might have some success using the following in step 2:

```
Turbolinks
  .controller
  .pushHistoryWithLocationAndRestorationIdentifier(PRODUCT_URL, Turbolinks.uuid())
```

---

It's worth noting that whilst this is a public method, it's not documented, and therefore maybe removed in future versions. However, given that Turbolinks is rather stable, it should be reasonably safe to use.

Hope that helps.